# Unable to install dual boot Ubuntu with Windows 10, both in UEFI mode (black screen after GRUB)

Tags: dual-boot, nvidia, uefi

I have a Dell XPS 15 9550, with Nvidia graphics card. My Windows 10 runs in UEFI mode, and I want to dual boot it with Ubuntu. When I try to install Ubuntu 20.04.2 from USB prepared with Rufus, MBR(UEFI or Legacy) selected, it would always install in legacy mode (It would directly boot into Linux when I change the firmware settings to Legacy, and directly into Windows 10 when UEFI is selected). If I prepare the USB with Ubuntu using Rufus to boot in UEFI only (GPT, FAT32) it does not boot at all. Grub screen appears, and when I select Ubuntu I get a black screen (but the PC stays on, it does not keep rebooting or cycling). I have also tried different distributions (like Mint), but the same thing happens. I tried the same USB with a different PC and it boots normally with any distribution. I tried different ports on my PC, and a different USB but it still won't work.

I have tried disabling secure boot, fast startup, hibernation, disabling legacy option roms, disabling attempt legacy boot. I tried increasing brightness after GRUB, changing GRUB boot options (adding nomodeset, changing to no splash, nouveau.modeset=0).

I have also tried to install Ubuntu in legacy mode, and then switch it to UEFI using boot repair, and I do see the "Separate /boot/efi partition" line (there is indeed and efi partition present in my PC), but the boot-repair tool requires disabling legacy mode in firmware settings first. I don't know how to proceed after this since my PC boots directly into Windows 10 if I disable legacy, so I can't access Linux or boot-repair anymore.

I have even tried disabling NVIDIA, since I also have the integrated graphics card, but it did not do a thing (maybe it only applied to my Windows session since I did it there).

I have been trying to set this up for the last couple of days and I have tried all of the suggestions that I found on other threads/forums. If anyone has any idea please help :)

Update: I have managed to successfully boot and install Fedora Linux, but Ubuntu and Mint get stuck at black screen after GRUB

Comment: Be sure to only boot in UEFI boot mode. New versions of Ubuntu have Safe Graphics Boot option on installer which adds nomodeset.
At grub menu you can use e for edit, scroll to linux line and replace quiet splash with nomodeset.
How to set NOMODESET and other kernel boot options in grub2 - both BIOS liveCD & grub first boot (also UEFI with grub) 
How to add boot parameters,  grub menu after install (also grub when UEFI)
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/KernelBootParameters Should be similar for 20.04. Ubuntu 16 on the DELL XPS15 9550 Tutorial
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2345444

Comment: Thanks for your reply and the suggestions. I just read the tutorial you linked and it is mostly about setting it up to work properly after installation. Unfortunately, there is not much information on the installation itself, or dual booting. I already tried adding nomodeset, changing to no splash, adding nouveau.modeset=0. I boot in UEFI mode only (switch off all the legacy options), but then it gets stuck after GRUB screen. The only way to install Ubuntu that I found was to allow legacy and install it in legacy mode, but my Windows is in UEFI so it is not practical :(

Comment: Have you updated UEFI and if SSD, updated its firmware? You can convert a legacy MBR boot install of Ubuntu on a gpt partitioned drive to UEFI, just by using Boot-Repair in UEFI mode & reinstalling grub. But you have to boot live installer in UEFI mode, is that the issue? Or is it after install? Is UEFI Secure Boot off? UEFI fast boot off? Windows fast start up off(Windows will turn back on with updates, so check again or whenever an issue). Are drive(s) in UEFI set to AHCI, not Intel RST? But install AHCI drivers into Windows first.

Comment: I have installed all the updates available, including the firmware ones. I have also disabled secure boot and Windows fast start up. I am unable to find the UEFI fast boot that you are referring to (I looked in my boot options). Could you point me to it? Yes, I have tried installing in legacy and using boot repair, but it requires me to disable legacy in order to repair the system. If legacy is disabled, I am unable to start the live USB (black screen after GRUB). I have also changed the setting to AHCI, since I got a warning that it needs to be done.

Comment: Black screen is usually video issue. Safe Graphics Boot option on installer adds nomodeset. or use nomodeset boot parameter in grub's Linux line. At grub menu you can use e for edit, scroll to linux line and replace quiet splash with nomodeset.
How to set NOMODESET and other kernel boot options in grub2 - both BIOS liveCD & grub first boot ( also UEFI with grub) 
How to add boot parameters,  grub menu after install (also grub when UEFI)
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/KernelBootParameters &  https://www.reddit.com/r/Dell/comments/b5r7c2/xps_15_9560_windows_fast_boot_problem/